# Disable progress bar glow effect

Tags: c#, winforms, progress-bar

For the default ProgressBar control, when the value is less than the max value, there is a glow effect (white part in bottom progress bar). Is there a simple way to disable the glow?

[image]

Comment: You could mess around with [ProgressBarRenderer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.progressbarrenderer.aspx) - there's an example for a vertical bar on that page, I'm sure you could alter it for your purposes. Not exactly "simple", though. There isn't a "change this property" solution, afaik.

Comment: Thanks @GrantWinney - is there any way to change the colour of the paused progressbar from yellow to green?

Comment: The last time I checked the consense was: Write your own!

Comment: It is not a "glow effect", it is an *animation*.  Moves from left to right, tells the user that your program is not hung-up.  So, your program is probably hung-up.  Don't shoot the messenger, fix the problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Windows Forms ProgressBar: Easiest way to start/stop marquee?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/312936/windows-forms-progressbar-easiest-way-to-start-stop-marquee)

Answer (score 1):

1. Set the ProgressBar.Minimum to what will be progress bar's value.
2. Set the ProgressBar.Value to equal the ProgressBar.Minimum.
3. Set the ProgressBar.Minimum to zero.
   Presto - no glow.

Works on toolstrip progress bars. 'Don't know about Forms.ProgressBar but seems like it should.

Comment: Wow, this actually does work!  I wouldn't suggest relying on what I assume is undocumented behavior, but what a convenient hack!

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone was wondering, I solved this by using the custom progress bar class in the second answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3529928/how-do-i-put-text-on-progressbar). The custom progress bar doesn't have a glow effect, and it also has the feature of allowing custom text on the progress bar. I also used the third answer ("Avoid flickering text") to solve the flicker problem.