# Richtextbox multiple back colors

Tags: c#, winforms

I saw this cool thing about having a `RichTextBox` like a "progress bar" if we can call it like that from another window application and I was trying to do the same.

I was looking at the methods and I couldn't apply any of them on what I'm looking for, I tried to see if there was a similar question but I didn't get so lucky.

How can I accomplish the same result?

Looks like a Richtextbox to me
[image]

Based on what Jimi told me I will to explain what I need. The string inside label rappresents a timer which has to change the color in red when it reaches the end, before of that, like at 10 minutes I want it to be Yellow, using that like an alert.

The way the method is wroten doesn't let me to choose which color I want. After that, when the timer is stopped by a button, I want the label to redraws itself and makes it blank without having any kind of colors, looking like a "textbox".

Comment: It would help us if you could show which RichTextBox you plan to use. Is it in WPF or Winforms, that might matter a bit? It looks like that particular effect is maybe easier to accomplish with a Label and some Panels. Are you sure a RichTextBox is what you need?

Comment: 1. Most probably a custom implemented control... did you try something, could you please edit the question and add your source code? 2. Did you see this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3529928/how-do-i-put-text-on-progressbar

Comment: You can do it with anything you can paint on. Could be a Label or a Panel.

Comment: IMO iIt's a picture box Control with drawing, the % is just a label inside.

Comment: I'm using Winforms, sorry about that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a label used as a ProgressBar.
Just an example (quite raw, what I could do with the time I had), but it shows how you can paint the surface of a Control that provides a [Paint()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.paint) event.

It uses a [Timer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.timer) class to increase a value and generates a progress bar effect by calling the [Label.Invalidate()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.invalidate) method, which raises the Label's Paint event, executing whatever code you have in the `label1_Paint()` handler.

If you want to test it, paste this code inside a Form which contains a Button (`button1`) to start the Timer and a Label (`label1`) that generates the graphic effect.
Then assign the two events - `Click()` to the `Button` and `Paint()` to the `Label`.

This is how it looks like:

[image]

```
Timer timer;
private bool TimerStarted = false;
private float ProgressMaxValue = 100;
private float Progress = 0;
private int seconds = 0;
private int cents = 0;

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (TimerStarted) { TimerStop(); return; }
    timer = new Timer();
    timer.Interval = 20;
    Progress = 0;
    seconds = 0;
    cents = 0;
    timer.Tick += (s, ev) => {
        ++Progress;
        if (Progress > ProgressMaxValue) { TimerStop(); return; }
        cents += (timer.Interval / 5);
        if (cents > 99) { cents = 0; ++seconds; }
        this.label1.Invalidate();
    };
    TimerStarted = true;
    timer.Start();
}

private void TimerStop()
{
    timer.Stop();
    timer.Dispose();
    TimerStarted = false;
}

private void label1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    StringFormat format = new StringFormat() {
        Alignment = StringAlignment.Center,
        LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Center
    };

    e.Graphics.Clear(this.label1.BackColor);
    Rectangle rect = label1.ClientRectangle;
    rect.Inflate(-1, -1);
    e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.LimeGreen, rect);
    RectangleF ProgressBar = new RectangleF(
                new PointF(3, 3),
                new SizeF((((float)rect.Width - 3) / ProgressMaxValue) * Progress, rect.Height - 4));
    e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.YellowGreen, ProgressBar);
    e.Graphics.DrawString($"0.{seconds.ToString("D2")}.{cents.ToString("D2")}", label1.Font, Brushes.White, rect, format);
}
```

Comment: I really appreciate your example code man. I was trying to use it to better undestand how it works, it looks like the invalidate() method doesn't work in my project because it doesn't draw the progress bar or anything, the lable remains the same, could you please explain me why?

Comment: @Zxhammelzx  Did you bind the events handlers (`label1_Paint` and `button1_Click`) to the corresponding Controls (a `Button` and a `Label`)? The `Invalidate()` method just raises the corresponding Control's Paint event. If you copy/paste this code into a Form, the Form must have a Button and a Label (as shown in the graphic example). Then, in the Form Designer, using the Control Properties panel, switch to Events view (Lightning Bolt symbol) and assign the event to the Control.

Comment: I was missing the "_1" at the end of the name of the event, feels bad man. You were really helpful man! Thanks a lot.

Comment: I did that. Also, I dont't know if we go OT like that, could you please explain me how I can change what's inside the DrawnString and set a different color of the DrawRectangle, is that even possible? I'm not talking about changing them into the paint method, I'm asking if it is possible after the drowing was done. Thank you

Comment: @Zxhammelzx  This is not OT, because it's related to your OP (Original Post). Yes, it's possible. If you are building a `Custom Control` or a `UserControl` it is also probably required, to have means to specify different colors for the `Text` and the `ProgressBar` properties. I'll make an edit to show how (as soon as I have some free time).

Comment: I updated my post and I tried to explain as clear as possible what I'm trying to accomplish, thank you again.