# Windows Forms:RightToLeft propety

Tags: c#, winforms, tabcontrol, right-to-left

I have a problem with tabControl RightToLeftProperty. I have set the RightToLeft property to Yes, and RightToLeftLayout property to true. But I got this result.
[image]

The text has been moved to right, but the tabs still stay in left, and the text is clickable, but tabs no. What may be the problem ? Thanks for help

Comment: The Visual Styles renderer for TabControl is a bug factory.  No repro on Windows 8.  Check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/299983/17034) for a possible workaround.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you set the "RightToLeft" property to Yes and "RightToLeftLayout" property to true, then the tab should move to the right side. surely it will work. please check your code or post your code.

or

you can do this through code, for example

```
Point p = new Point();
p.X =  tabControl1.Location.X + 5;
p.Y = tabControl1.Location.Y + 5;
tabControl1.Location = p;
```