# Timepicker does not show the arrow beside it

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, windows-forms-designer

I would like to know i have removed Application.EnableVisualStyles () as the program i develop for progress bar it will be easier if i remove that statement of "Application.EnableVisualStyles". The problem i face was, when i put datetimepicker i set the showupdown to true, the arrow in show up down does not display as formerly with the statement "Application.EnabledStyles". Is there a way i can solve it without addding "Application.EnableVisualStyles". Thanks

It is like this for the datetimepicker
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1r5lG.png)

i want like this for the datetimepicker with the enabled visual style removed
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uFO3U.png)

Comment: Set the ShowUpDown property back to False.  You can't have both, regardless of the visual style.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to use the old ProgressBar, this Hans Passant answer [How do I disable visual styles for just one control, and not its children?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/299983/719186) shows how to turn visual styles off for a single control.  I've adapted that code for your progress bar:

```
public class OldProgressBar : ProgressBar {

  [DllImportAttribute("uxtheme.dll")]
  private static extern int SetWindowTheme(IntPtr hWnd, string appName, string idlist);

  protected override void OnHandleCreated(EventArgs e) {
    SetWindowTheme(this.Handle, "", "");
    base.OnHandleCreated(e);
  }
}
```

Now you can use `Application.EnableVisualStyles();` and still use the old progress bar control.

Comment: bro... thanks thanks thanks alot... you are really brilliant.. and thanks so much.. for ur help....