# TabControl ItemSize with TabPage ImageKey

Tags: c#, winforms, tabcontrol

I have a `TabControl` where I want to keep the tabs to a fixed size and I want icons in the tabs. I have set `TabControl.SizeMode = Fixed` and `TabControl.ItemSize = 100, 18`. I have also set `TabControl.ImageList` and am assigning images to the tabs via `TabPage.ImageKey`.

Here is what it looks like if I comment-out assigning the `ImageKey`:

[image: image1]

And here is what it looks like if I am assigning the `ImageKey`:

[image: image2]

Is there some sort of "alignment" for the icons? I want them to be on the far left in the blank space, but instead they are starting where the text starts. Any suggestions?

(BTW - if I set `TabControl.SizeMode = Normal`, I get the tab content the way I want it, but the tabs aren't a fixed size):

[image: image3]

Comment: As I know, there is no direct way to do that, unless you draw the items by yourself through DrawItem events in tabControl.

Comment: The visual styles renderer for TabControl has been notoriously buggy for a very long time.  Yup, looks like they screwed it up again in Win10 Fall Creators edition.  A workaround of sorts is to disable visual styles for only the tab control, not for the tab pages or the rest of your UI.  https://stackoverflow.com/a/299983/17034

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can verify the issue that you are seeing with `TabControl.SizeMode = Fixed` (on Windows 10).  I initially seen it in the designer when configuring a `TabPage` with an icon.  However the irritating thing is that the issue corrected itself if the designer is closed and reopened.  This suggests a window style setting of some sort and there are some [Tab Control Styles](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb760549(v=vs.85).aspx) set in the [CreateParams Property](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/TabControl.cs,706ed3e4f4c6ca37,references) based on the `SizeMode` Property.  However, I found no solution in attempting to apply the `TCS_FORCEICONLEFT` style.  If the `ImageIndex` property is set prior to the control being shown, then the alignment is as desired.  So I figured that there must be something being configured on handle creation.

If you call the form's `RecreateHandle` method after setting the TabPage.ImageIndex property, the form redraws and all looks good.  However this cause the form to *blink*.  Calling the [Control.RecreateHandle](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.recreatehandle(v=vs.110).aspx) method on the TabControl also works. This is a protected method and would necessitate using a derived TabControl to expose the method or you could use Reflection to invoke the method.

```
public class MyTC : TabControl
{
    public void FixIcon()
    {
        RecreateHandle();
    }
}
```

Comment: You can have the same effect (after you have assigned the `ImageList` and the Items `ImageIndex`), setting: `tabControl1.SizeMode = TabSizeMode.Normal;` and immediately after: `tabControl1.SizeMode = TabSizeMode.Fixed;` (in the environments I could test - Win10 Fall Creators edition not included).

Comment: Similarly to @Jimi 's idea - it actually worked for me to just set `tabControl.ItemSize = new Size(100, 18);` (the same size as set in the designer) *again* after setting the `tabPage.ImageKey`