# MonthCalendar color not changing

Tags: c#, winforms, monthcalendar

I am trying to change the color of the MonthCalendar in c# but it won't change when I try to adjust it in the settings.

[image: SOQ61665693]

As you can see, I changed the colors in the menu, but the calendar still looks the same. Does anyone know why?

Comment: Create a new class that derives from MonthCalendar and then follow the example given here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/298486/how-do-i-disable-visual-styles-for-just-one-control-and-not-its-children

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is from your window visual style:
[look here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/how-to-change-monthcalendar-control-appearance)

in c#

```
using System.Windows.Forms.VisualStyles;

Application.VisualStyleState=VisualStyleState.NoneEnabled;
```