# How to change C# Progress Bar Style in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm trying to make a progress bar like this:[Old style Window progress bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GWjDg.png)

But i get this instead:[Glass progress bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oSNkF.png)

Can anyone help me with the solution?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/298486/how-do-i-disable-visual-styles-for-just-one-control-and-not-its-children/299983#299983

Comment: Take a look at [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/298486/how-do-i-disable-visual-styles-for-just-one-control-and-not-its-children/299983#299983). That should help you achieve what you want.